# Cisco 1811w routing issues

Tags: cisco

I have a Cisco 1811w and I'm just trying to get a basic configuring for now. I'm using cable internet (TWC) on fa0 (just regular internal dhcp for now, no bridging done yet) and fa1 as the internal 10.0.0.0/24

PCs connected to fa1 do get handed dhcp and the router settings, but nothing can ping, either on the PC or in the router. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

## The ping test from within the router:

```
Router#ping 8.8.8.8
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 8.8.8.8, timeout is 2 seconds:
.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
```

## IP info:

```
FastEthernet0              192.168.0.5     YES DHCP   up                    up      
FastEthernet1              10.0.0.1        YES NVRAM  up                    down (nothing plugged into 1 at the moment)
```

## Running-config:

```
Current configuration : 1758 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$NMgE$p0dWLAM1aVTRcqnrIL2Vu1
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
dot11 syslog
!
!
ip cef
no ip dhcp use vrf connectedip dhcp excluded-address 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.10
!         
ip dhcp pool Lan1DHCP
   import all
   network 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 10.0.0.1 
   dns-server 10.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 
!         
!         
!         
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!         
!         
!         
!         
archive   
 log config
  hidekeys
!         
!         
!         
!         
!         
interface Dot11Radio0
 no ip address
 shutdown 
 speed basic-1.0 basic-2.0 basic-5.5 6.0 9.0 basic-11.0 12.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0
 station-role root
!         
interface Dot11Radio1
 no ip address
 shutdown 
 speed basic-6.0 9.0 basic-12.0 18.0 basic-24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0
 station-role root
!         
interface FastEthernet0
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!         
interface FastEthernet1
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!         
interface FastEthernet2
!         
interface FastEthernet3
!         
interface FastEthernet4
!         
interface FastEthernet5
!         
interface FastEthernet6
!         
interface FastEthernet7
!         
interface FastEthernet8
!         
interface FastEthernet9
!         
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!         
interface Async1
 no ip address
 encapsulation slip
!         
ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 FastEthernet0
!         
!         
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list 101 interface FastEthernet0 overload
!         
access-list 101 permit ip 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
```

Comment: Show us the output of `sh ip route` and try an extended ping from interface FastEthernet0.

Comment: Gateway of last resort is 0.0.0.0 to network 0.0.0.0

C    192.168.0.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0
S*   0.0.0.0/0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0

Comment: Can you change `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 FastEthernet0` to `ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.0.1` or whatever your next-hop IP is. Specifying a next-hop interface rather than IP address is generally used on point-to-point links.

Comment: @[Matt Morrow](https://serverfault.com/users/407392/matt-morrow), if it works, then you might want to change your `secret` password - Cisco's password encryption is pretty trivial to break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MarkoPolo is right. There's problem with default gateway. But I think you should use default gateway, which Cisco can get from​ your ISP via DHCP:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dhcp
```

Comment: I just don't know what I'm doing wrong. I reset the config so I could just start over. If I have just fa0 grabbing dhcp from the modem, I can ping just fine inside the router - 100% packet xfer. But once I enable nat for fa0 and fa1, i start getting really bad packet drops, from 40 to 60%, and severely slow dns lookups.

Comment: Look for transmit and receive errors on fa0 and fa1 interfaces. Check that the router has one default gateway.

Comment: I finally got it. For one I had 2 routes setup, one to fa0 directly and another to DHCP. I discovered having a route to an interface by name causes arp requests to be sent on each hop because it is a broadcast device. So I deleted that and left the one for DHCP, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If it will help anyone else, my config is:

`version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
enable secret 5 $1$XweJ$NMtNuu/R4emfBU0rpjamg1
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
dot11 syslog
!
!
ip cef
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.0.0.1 10.0.0.10
!

ip dhcp pool Lan1DHCP
   import all
   network 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0
   default-router 10.0.0.1 
   dns-server 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 
!

!

!

multilink bundle-name authenticated
!

!

!

!

archive

 log config
  hidekeys
!

!

!

!

!

interface Dot11Radio0
 no ip address
 shutdown 
 speed basic-1.0 basic-2.0 basic-5.5 6.0 9.0 basic-11.0 12.0 18.0 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0
 station-role root
!

interface Dot11Radio1
 no ip address
 shutdown 
 speed basic-6.0 9.0 basic-12.0 18.0 basic-24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0
 station-role root
!

interface FastEthernet0
 ip address dhcp
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!

interface FastEthernet1
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!

interface FastEthernet2
!

interface FastEthernet3
!

interface FastEthernet4
!

interface FastEthernet5
!

interface FastEthernet6
!

interface FastEthernet7
!

interface FastEthernet8
!

interface FastEthernet9
!

interface Vlan1
 no ip address
!

interface Async1
 no ip address
 encapsulation slip
!

ip forward-protocol nd
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 dhcp
!

!

no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip nat inside source list 101 interface FastEthernet0 overload
!

access-list 101 permit ip 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
!

!

!

!

!

!

control-plane
!

!

line con 0
line 1

 modem InOut
 stopbits 1
 speed 115200
 flowcontrol hardware
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 login

!

end`